# Requeuing message to Azure Topic Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Problem: I have a Azure Topic Topic1 with Subscriptions Subscription-A, Subscription-B, Subscription-C
Each Subscription is listen to by an Azure function and it uses the message to perform unique action like charging customer or Updating another subsystem etc.
If the  execution in one of the functions results in error , I would like to requeue the message into that specific subscription for execution after a delay say 1 min. not right way. [ Currently, If the function results in error, message is retried right away couple of times before pushing to dead letter. Looks like default behavior by Azure service bus and functions]

I can not resend a message to Topic1 as that message would be read by all the 3 subscriptions. I don't want this as the other message were processed successfully by the respective subscription/functions. This requeued message should be filtered out by other subscriptions on this topic.

Any ideas or suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: If a given subscriber is failing to process the message, it should be retried on the subscription (queue) that was failing, not returned to the topic. You came to the exact conclusion as well. So what's the question then?

Comment: retry happened right way. I want to add incremental delay in attempt to retry

Comment: Correct. That's the default behavior for Functions today. Delayed retries are not available today). If you need that today, you'd have to build it yourself or use something that can handle it. Some libraries do it already. [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/previews/azure-functions-service-bus) does. Full disclosure: I contribute to that project.